# Is it possible to have common logback.xml for gradle multimodule project?

Tags: java, gradle, logging, logback

I have a multi-module Gradle project.
Each module has its own `logback.xml` in `src/{main|test}/resources`.
I would like to have logging configuration consolidated in one place and applied for the whole project.
Is there a way to do so?

I don't use Spring framework.

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar set up for Automation in my workplace and the solution we have here is that the logging for the whole automation project (all modules in the project) is implemented in a separate project. Which is then imported into the Automation framework as a grade dependency used by al the modules in the framework.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32771144)

Comment: @abdoSalm , I have updated my answer. Is that acceptable?